# Visual Studio Online - Live ID vs Work Accounts

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-devops

We're completely upgrading our production and development environment from co-located boxes to an Azure implementation and we'll be developing using Visual Studio Online.  Up until this point our dev has occurred on a Remote Desktop environment where developers were logging into Windows server and developing on that RDP box.

We want to set this up and we have some confusion about the Account types/set up types.

It appears there are two ways to set up our Azure and two ways to set up our developers.  We are a MS partner w/ some MSDN licenses and Azure credits.

So for Azure we can use our existing MS accounts and just set up an Azure Pay As You Go (PAYG) subscription.  This was suggested to us initially but it seems weird to have the entire companies Azure environment going through an individuals live ID.  Then we saw we can sign up as an Organization now and it uses Azure AD.  We have not been using Active Directory and we're not sure how much complexity this is going to add to our administration.  Is there a discernible difference/benefit to going one way or the other?

Then, when we sign up our developers we can either have everyone sign up with their live ID's (we have MSDN w/ VS Premium credits for all developers) or we can set them up using Active Directory with Work Accounts.  Having our credits allotted in work accounts sounds like a good way to control things at first reading, but it also seems a bit more complex.  I'm wondering if there is much difference between MSDN accounts signed up w/ live IDs or AD Work Accounts.  I can't find a real comparison article or pro/con type of discussion anywhere.

Comment: Using an Azure account linked to an MSDN subscription isn't allowed to be used for production anyways.  Something to keep in mind.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken that's why we have to either set up a PAYG subscription or set up a separate organization azure account.  Both of these pay services will allow me to go into production.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have already figured out the main differences.  As an organization, I would suggest signing up for Azure as an organization.  You can do that [here](https://account.windowsazure.com/organization).  This is going to give you the management capabilities for resources typically needed by an organization.

Your developers can continue to use the MSDN subscriptions. As Dylan commented, these are not to be used for production environments.  You should consider using these for Dev/Test environments and activating your MSDN benefits.  This will save you some money.  More on that [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/member-offers/msdn-benefits/).

Visual Studio Online will work with your Work Accounts and again give you more control over managing your online resources.  [This link](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/setup/sign-up-for-visual-studio-online) describes the sign-up process for both Microsoft Accounts and Work Accounts.  And if you scroll down a bit you will find your original question specifically addressed.

[image]

Finally, you can also add your Work Account(s) to your existing MSDN subscriptions if you like. This way you (and your developers) can use the same account credentials when accessing Azure Subscriptions.  Information on how to do that is available in [this link](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/setup/link-msdn-subscription-to-organizational-account-vs).

Your Work Account subscription should be limited to personnel responsible for managing your "production" environment.

After signing up for Azure as an Organization, you can add users to the directory as described [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-create-users/).  You can also add "external" users using their existing Microsoft Accounts.  It's just a few dialogs to add a user.

Comment: So we've signed up as an organization on Azure.  My co-worker and I both have MSDN accounts, VS Premium w/ MSDN (MPN).  In MSDN profile I clicked "Link to Work account" and put in my work account.  WHen I try to log into VS w/ that account it says "We couldn't find an account with that email address."  I think I'm fundamentally misunderstanding something.  I re-read those links in your post.   We are a partner and have a bunch of MSDN licenses we're using to sign up our developers, say 6 of them.  We want them to use their work accounts but I can't seem to even log in with mine.

Comment: Also, our VSO account is under my MSDN with a co-admin added.  So only when I deploy to production would anything hit the organization Azure account.  In this scenario I wouldn't want to log in as the organization to set up projects, does that sound right.  This is quite confusing (for me).

Comment: Logging into VS only accepts a Microsoft Account. The Work Account would apply to your VSO account.

Comment: VS 2015 supports logging in with OrgID.

Comment: You should be able to 'link' your MS account to your Work/Org account: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/setup/link-msdn-subscription-to-organizational-account-vs However I dont see this link myself so I dont know what I am to do!